# Change TreeListNode Index (Position) in DevExpree TreeList Control

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I'm using DevExpree XtraTreeList Control, I want to randomly Set one of the first levels nodes to be the first node in the Tree, nothing helpful shown in the TreeList Control's Methods nor in the TreeListNode Methods,

Please Advice.

Edit: **My Code**

```
 private void btnSetMaster_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Load reprot
            if (treeLstRprtDS.FocusedNode != null)
            {
                treeLstRprtDS.SetNodeIndex(treeLstRprtDS.FocusedNode,0);
                //Get selected underlying object
                ReportDataSource rprtDataSourceSelected =
                    (ReportDataSource)treeLstRprtDS.GetDataRecordByNode(treeLstRprtDS.FocusedNode);
                theReport.SetReportDataSourceAsMaster(rprtDataSourceSelected);
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**

**Note:** working on bound mode

---

**Solution:**

I implemented the CompareNodeValues Event for the XtrTreeList Control
[Read here...](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_CompareNodeValuestopic)

and then forced the tree to do sorting using Column.SortIndex [Read here...](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q267563.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wish to scroll the TreeList so that a certain node to be the top one?  If so, use the TreeList's [TopVisibleNodeIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_TopVisibleNodeIndextopic) property.  If you need a certain node to be the first one, you should sort the TreeList within its [CompareNodeValues](http://ms-help://DevExpress.NETv10.1/DevExpress.WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_CompareNodeValuestopic.htm) event handler.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the event first thing in the morning, and will update you with the results.

Comment: this helped http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q267563.aspx issue solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`SetNodeIndex` method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SetNodeIndextopic).

Comment: Yeah Right, according to the documentation http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SetNodeIndextopic If i set the index negative then the node must appears as first node, but nothing helped, I also tried to pass 0 as index